# Creating multi-dimensional array from multiple distinct arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I suspect this question has been answered before but i have dug and dug this great forum for an answer in vain.....

I have 3 arrays that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 19
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 2018
)

Array
(
    [1] => 19
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 2017
)

Array
(
    [1] => 18
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 2016
)
```

I would like to convert this 3 arrays into a multidimensional array to look something like this:

```
$mynewArray =  Array(

    [0] =>array(
        [1] => 19
        [2] => 2
        [3] => 2018
    )

    [1] =>array(
        [1] => 19
        [2] => 1
        [3] => 2017
    )

    [2] => array(
        [1] => 18
        [2] => 2
        [3] => 2016

    )
    )
```

How do i achieve this in Php?

Comment: `array($array1, $array2, $array3)`

Comment: What do you mean by "I have an array that looks like this". Do you have one array or three arrays?

Comment: They are three arrays that i want to convert into a multidimensional array @Barmar

Comment: It is just creating an array with array elements, like you would have make one with a list of strings or integers.

Comment: A multidimensional array is just an array whose elements are other arrays. So you create it the same way you create any other array, but the values happen to be those original 3 arrays.

Comment: @MainaMailu Your answer is first comment of this thread. Try.

Comment: @quickSwap when i use the suggestion on first comment i end up with something like this...`Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [1] => 19
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 2018
        )

)

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [1] => 19
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 2017
        )

)

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [1] => 18
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 2016
        )

)`

Comment: That's what you want, check your expected output and your this comment.

Comment: No. In my comment, i still end up with 3 arrays rather than one array with 3 arrays inside.

Comment: @MainaMailu *Check demo link and my answer for details.*

Answer (score 1):

[**Demo Link**](https://3v4l.org/adKI8).

You just need to add it in parent array as below,

```
$arr1 = [1 => 19, 2 => 2, 3 => 2018];
$arr2 = [1 => 19, 2 => 1, 3 => 2017];
$arr3 = [1 => 18, 2 => 2, 3 => 2016];
$mynewArray = [$arr1,$arr2,$arr3];
print_r($mynewArray);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [1] => 19
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 2018
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => 19
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 2017
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [1] => 18
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 2016
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can append your child arrays to the parent by

```
 $array1 = array("1"=>"1","2"=>"2","3"=>"3");
 $array2 = array("1"=>"1","2"=>"2","3"=>"3");

 $newarray = array($array1,$array2);
```